# Override dafault maven dependency resolution behaviour

Tags: maven

By default, maven resolves the dependency in the following structure when it tries to fetch from repo:

groupId:artifactId:type:classifier:version

Now, I would like to override the pattern with the below behaviour. Is there anyway we can achieve this.

groupId:artifactId:classifier:type:version

TIA.

Regards,
Suresh Kumar.

Comment: Why? (before saying 'no')

Comment: My client has published an api from ivy repository. Which has artifact name and jar name are different so.

In ideal scenario, if artifact name is "data", then jar name will be like data-{version}.jar

But in my scenario, I have the artifact name as "data" and jar name is like data-config-{version}.jar 

You sure we cannot do right?

Comment: Consider using a repository manager that supports Ivy. As far as I know only Artifactory supports that. Repository managers contain the logic to make Ivy repositories accessable as Maven repositories.